# How to write a Excel C add-in function that return a string to Excel without memory leak?

Tags: c++, excel, memory-leaks, add-in, xll

I am writing an Excel XLL addin using C++, where I want my function to return a string to Excel using the predefined XLOPER12.

As I understanded, Excel require the function to return a pointer that points to a memory,and then it makes a shallow copy then goes away without clearing the memory allocated in the function. So if I write something like:

```
extern "C" LPXLOPER12 WINAPI strgen() {
    XLOPER12 res;

    res.xltype = xltypeString;
    res.val.str = (XCHAR*)malloc(2*sizeof(XCHAR));
    res.val.str[0] = (XCHAR)1;
    res.val.str[1] = L"X";

    return (LPXLOPER12)&xRes;
}
```

But apparently this will cause a memory leak. Someone suggests that I could declare res as static variable, but i don't really know how to initialize it.

All suggestions are welcomed.

Best

Comment: Neither the sample code nor the answer are good. In both cases, `res` is declared on the stack, and its address is returned. This will produce a crash in the best case (because you'll immediately see there is a problem) and reasonable results in the worst case (because this is a problem in the code and won't be caught right away).

Comment: @David I edit answer, because I found that problem too. BTW, in original code returns some `xRes`'s address. I don't' know what is that

Comment: Memory management is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687840.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save yourself some trouble and use https://xll.codeplex.com. Complete code to register and define the function is

```
static AddIn12 xai_strgen(
    L"?strgen", L"STRGEN",
    XLL_LPOPER12, L"");
LPOPER12 WINAPI strgen() 
{
#pragma XLLEXPORT
    static XLOPER12 xRes(L"X");

    return &xRes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to declare static array and return it's address

```
XCHAR s_res[3] = {0};
XLOPER12 res;
extern "C" LPXLOPER12 WINAPI strgen() {


res.xltype = xltypeString;
res.val.str = (XCHAR*)s_res;
res.val.str[0] = (XCHAR)1;
res.val.str[1] = L"X";

return (LPXLOPER12)&res;
}
```

Pay an attention that you shouldn't move `s_res` inside a function, because it will have a stack storage, that will be cleared when the function returns

Comment: thank you, but seems this is still not thread safe. I just learned from msdn that I can actually do this via xlAutoRemove function call ...

Comment: IMHO you should suggest to @indiv to make his comment as an answer and accept it

Comment: First of all, ask @indiv to **answer** (not a comment) and then accept it